# Combining not in Query with date range filter yieds zero result

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql, repository

Query to know orders not having certain status between date range returns zero result

Linq To SQL

```
  string[] notHavingStaus = { "CantFind", "Review" };

_repository.Query<Entities.Order>()
            .Where(x => (!notHavingStaus.Contains(x.ApplicationStatus))
            && x.OrderDate >= fromdate && x.OrderDate <= todate);
```

Generated Query Something like

```
/****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/
SELECT *
  FROM [dbo].[Order]
  Where (not ApplicationStatus in ('CantFind' , 'Review')) and
     (OrderDate>='2019-07-16' and OrderDate<='2019-07-17')
```

Comment: @LukaszSzozda nulls can come into result

Comment: And when you run that SQL query directly, what happens?